# Counting values with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count values that are greater than 0. Below you can see my data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id_n":["1","2","3","4","5"],
                               "Sales":[0,1,1,4,5],
                               "Sales1":[0,1,5,4,5],
                               "Sales2":[1,0,0,4,5]
                  })
```

Now I want to count rows that have values greater than 0, and put them into the separate column you can see pic below

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['counttotal'] =(df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')>0).sum(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['counttotal'] = df[['Sales','Sales1','Sales2']].gt(0).sum(axis=1)
```